# Spring RPC with hessian over HTTP works fine on maven tomcat plugin, but return http 500 error on Tomcat server

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, hessian

I work with Spring RPC with hessian over HTTP, it works fine when I tried it on maven tomcat-plugin(Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.29, Java 7).

But after I packaged it with maven-war plugin and deployed on a tomcat server.(I have tried both 6.0.36 and 7.0.37), the RPC call returns 500 error.

I'm not sure what's the difference between these two usage of tomcat. RPC call is from same procedure to it's HTTP service, I mean they use same code. Two parameters are both String.

I have tried to add a MIME-TYPE as "application/x-hessian" to tomcat server, 500 is still there.

Anyone knows what's wrong with my tomcat server?

### update question:

Thank you @Ralf, you are right, the old log didn't show the server error, I added new logs.

The server side log shows error about HessianProtocolException, and I found a method to resolve this: down grade the hessian version to 3.1.5, now the RPC works.

But, the question is still there, why when I use 4.0.33, the tomcat started by maven plugin works fine, the stand alone tomcat shows error?

#### My interface is

```
public interface RemoteMessage {
    public boolean callMethod(String number, String content);
}
```

#### dependencies like this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-remoting</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.8</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.caucho</groupId>
  <artifactId>hessian</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.33</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

#### error log from server side:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Hessian skeleton invocation failed; nested exception is com.caucho.hessian.io.HessianProtocolException: expected string at 0x6d
    at org.springframework.remoting.caucho.HessianServiceExporter.handleRequest(HessianServiceExporter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:49)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:139)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: com.caucho.hessian.io.HessianProtocolException: expected string at 0x6d
    at com.caucho.hessian.io.Hessian2Input.error(Hessian2Input.java:2943)
    at com.caucho.hessian.io.Hessian2Input.expect(Hessian2Input.java:2891)
    at com.caucho.hessian.io.Hessian2Input.readString(Hessian2Input.java:1398)
    at com.caucho.hessian.io.Hessian2Input.readMethod(Hessian2Input.java:308)
    at com.caucho.hessian.server.HessianSkeleton.invoke(HessianSkeleton.java:245)
    at com.caucho.hessian.server.HessianSkeleton.invoke(HessianSkeleton.java:217)
    at org.springframework.remoting.caucho.Hessian2SkeletonInvoker.invoke(Hessian2SkeletonInvoker.java:67)
    at org.springframework.remoting.caucho.HessianServiceExporter.handleRequest(HessianServiceExporter.java:147)
    ... 53 more
```

#### error log is this:

```
 com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.EndpointMethodHandler invoke
 SEVERE: 500: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://localhost:8080/test/rpc/callMethod
 com.caucho.hessian.client.HessianConnectionException: 500: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://localhost:8080/test/rpc/callMethod
      at com.caucho.hessian.client.HessianURLConnection.sendRequest(HessianURLConnection.java:145)
      at com.caucho.hessian.client.HessianProxy.sendRequest(HessianProxy.java:296)
      at com.caucho.hessian.client.HessianProxy.invoke(HessianProxy.java:171)
      at $Proxy92.sengMessage(Unknown Source)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
      at org.springframework.remoting.caucho.HessianClientInterceptor.invoke(HessianClientInterceptor.java:165)
      at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
      at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
      at $Proxy93.sengMessage(Unknown Source)
      at com.sample.test.service.impl.ServiceImpl.callMethod(ServiceImpl.java:887)
      at com.sample.test.service.impl.ServiceImpl$$FastClassByCGLIB$$d60c9e4c.invoke(<generated>)
      at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
      at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:618)
      at com.sample.test.service.impl.ServiceImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$cf1025d0.callMethod(<generated>)
      at com.sample.test.service.impl.BPUserCardProcServiceImpl.handle(BPUserCardProcServiceImpl.java:39)
      at com.sample.test.ws.TestWebServiceImpl.BPUserCardProc(TestWebServiceImpl.java:76)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
      at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.InstanceResolver$1.invoke(InstanceResolver.java:250)
      at com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube$2.invoke(InvokerTube.java:150)
      at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.EndpointMethodHandler.invoke(EndpointMethodHandler.java:261)
      at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(SEIInvokerTube.java:100)
      at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:641)
      at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:600)
      at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:585)
      at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:482)
      at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:314)
      at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:608)
      at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:259)
      at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.invokeAsync(ServletAdapter.java:207)
      at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doGet(WSServletDelegate.java:159)
      at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doPost(WSServletDelegate.java:194)
      at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSSpringServlet.doPost(WSSpringServlet.java:52)
      at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
      at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:186)
      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
      at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
      at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
      at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
      at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
      at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
      at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
      at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
      at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
 Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://localhost:8080/test/rpc/callMethod
      at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
      at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1674)
      at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1672)
      at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
      at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1670)
      at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1243)
      at com.caucho.hessian.client.HessianURLConnection.sendRequest(HessianURLConnection.java:125)
      ... 61 more
 Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://localhost:8080/test/rpc/callMethod
      at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1625)
      at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)
      at com.caucho.hessian.client.HessianURLConnection.sendRequest(HessianURLConnection.java:112)
      ... 61 more
```

Comment: You need to look at the server side error log to get leads on what is amiss. The client log only reports that the there was an internal server error, but not its nature.

Comment: Hessian will log out more information if you turn the logging level up to FINE (or TRACE if using Log4J). That may give more clues to why this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove spring-remoting dependency. It conflicts with latest version of hessian library. I faced the same problem & after googling I found this [HessianConnectionException: (HTTP) 500 error when using Hessian 4.0.7 & Spring 3.1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10553046/hessianconnectionexception-http-500-error-when-using-hessian-4-0-7-spring-3) .

Comment: Thank you @anasanjaria, I've changed the version of hessian and avoid the problem.
Your answer make sense

Answer (score -2):

Try this command:

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests
```